# Finding a job in the UK while abroad

Tags: united-kingdom, job-hunting

I am a British-born man who emigrated to Switzerland in 2008 and I am looking at returning to England as life here is not as I thought and simply finding work after being laid off is proving very very difficult - I have been almost 3 years unemployed...

Anyway I would prefer to line up a job in England before heading back but this is proving tricky as well and would like to hear other peoples experiences in this matter.

Are there actually agencies which are in place specially for my situation?

Comment: What field are you in?

Comment: administration, finance, back office, support

Answer (score 4):

Most employment agencies in the UK will deal via phone/email so that shouldn't be a problem.  Bigger issues will be interviews (initially likely via phone but a face-to-face may be harder, do you expect them to pay flights?), and the fact you have a 3 year hole in your CV.

The issue is likely to be an assumption you'll be looking for relocation assistance,  which can be fine if your skills are in demand and hard to get in the destination, but given you've been 3 years unemployed that may be a hard sell.

I would look to getting back to the UK first, likely easier in the first instance.

Comment: thanks for your reply - No I would not expect them to pay for flights at all... I think my enquiry is more along the lines of Is it easier to be on the ground so to speak, in the market place...Here in Switzerland the employment agencies , in general, almost frown upon personal visits and just refer you to their website!. The last time I was in the UK and unemployed I found agencies to be far more forgiving in that regard and you could actually pop in  get to speak to someone face to face and become more than just a CV on a website...has that situation changed much?